# Proper Restful API design guide

Tags: rest

I'm designing Restful API before making backend server. This service is small Instagram and I wanna know my restful design is proper for REST principles.

**Authentication**

- Create account : POST /auth/user
- Delete account : DELETE /auth/user
- Login : POST /auth/session
- Logout : DELETE /auth/session

**Post**

- Load feed : GET /posts
- Create post : POST /posts
- Read post : GET /posts/:post_id
- Delete post : DELETE /posts/:post_id
- Read comments : GET /posts/:post_id/comments
- Create comment : POST /posts/:post_id/comments
- Delete comment : DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id
- Create like : POST /posts/:post_id/likes
- Read likes : GET /posts/:post_id/likes
- Delete like : DELETE /posts/:post_id/likes/:like_id

**Follow**

- Read followings : GET /followings/:user_id
- Create following : POST /followings/:user_id
- Delete following : DELETE /followings/:user_id
- Read followers : GET /followers/:user_id

**Activities**

- Read activities : GET /activities

**Search**

- Read search : GET /filter/:search_term

**Explore**

- Read explore : GET /similars

I'm new to Restful API design, so I wanna advice or modification for my design. Is it proper to principles?

Comment: It looks pretty great to me!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to Restful API design, so I wanna advice or modification for my design. Is it proper to principles?

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers.  It doesn't care how you design your resources.  What it does care about is hypermedia, and caching, and using standardized definitions of things so that we can use general purpose components to achieve useful work.

```
GET /activities
GET /95d9f08a-fb79-4a18-a630-b2e31ad7039a
```

Both of these URI are *fine*; general purpose components will do the right thing in either case because the machines don't *care* about spelling (provided that the spellings that you do use are consistent with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)) - an identifier is an identifier, and the machines don't try to extract any semantic information from them.  Which means that your server, acting on its own authority, can choose whatever spellings you want.

Put another way, we fuss over the spellings of URI for the same reasons that we fuss over the spelling of variable names - to make things easier for other people.  So any internally consistent spelling convention is *fine*, in exactly the same way that any consistent convention for naming variables/functions/classes is fine.

Using GET for all of your reads, and POST for all of your writes, is fine - the web was catastrophically successful, after all.  POST is somewhat interesting, in that you want to make sure that you understand the implications for [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).